# Publishing very slow in fatwire CMS

Tags: content-management-system, publishing, fatwire

I was trying to publisg assets from one environment to another. It was almost very slow and not progressing further. Could any body suggest what can be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try segmenting your assets and publishing in smaller goups

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it boils down to finding the culprit asset which causes the entire batch to stall. This is why segmenting slow publishes can help narrow the issue.  Also check if there are any assets checked out in your target destination.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to check

You can set VERBOSE=TRUE on the publish destination config, to make the UI write a more detailed log. It's important to know exactly what is slow, whether its the movement of assets to target or the cache flush/potential rebuild on target.

Check the futuretense.txt on source and target for any telltale error or curious messages, if nothing is appearing there then maybe the logging is suppressed. You should have INFO level for most loggers by default, and if still nothing is appearing then set com.fatwire.logging.cs=DEBUG and retry.

Generally speaking if this is a production system, and its not a huge number of assets being published, then cache flush is where most time is spent. And, if it is configured to do so, cache regeneration. The verbose publish log will tell you how much is being flushed.

If the cause of slowness can't be determined from inspecting the logs, then consider taking periodic thread dumps (source and target) during the publish, to see what is happening under the hood. Perhaps the system is slow waiting on a resource like shared disk (a common problem).

Phil

Answer (score 0):

To understand better, you will need to find at what step the publishing process is stuck. As you know, the publishing is process is composed of 5 steps, first two (data gather and serialization) happens at source, the third (data transfer) happens between source & destination, and the last two (de-serialization & cache clear) happens at delivery.

One weird situation that I have come across is the de-serialization step in which it was trying to update Locale tree in each real time publish. The then Fatwire support suggested us to add &PUBLISHLOCALETREE=false. This significantly improved the publish performance. Once again, this only applies if you're using locales/translations in your Site.